# How to list all inputs calculated?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Please note I have only started learning Python recently so looking for some pretty basic code.

I have a program that needs to calculate the Volumes of three types of shapes (cube, pyramid and ellipsoid) which is easy enough. The problem is that after the tester (user) has calculated many different volumes for all three shapes the program must output a list of the different shapes and all of the volumes it has calculated for each shape.

To better explain, say the user calculates the volumes of 3 cubes, 2 pyramids, and 5 ellipsoids. When the user types in "Quit" instead of a new shape, the program then must output:

"You have come to the end of the session.
The Volumes Calculated for each shape are shown below:
Cube: (list of all volumes calculated)
Pyramid: (List of all volumes calculated)
Ellipsoid: (List of all volumes calculated)"

Thank you in advance!
For the record using Pycharm  Edu 3.0.1 and Python 3.5.7

```
while True : 
shape =input("Please enter the shape you wish to find the volume of: ")                     
if shape == "cube":                                                                         
    sideLength = int(input("Please enter side Length: "))
    def main():                                                                             
        result1 = round(cubeVolume(sideLength),2)
        print ("A cube with side length {} has a volume {}".format(sideLength,result1))
    def cubeVolume(sideLength):                                                             
        volume = sideLength**3
        return volume
    main()
    continue                                                                                
elif shape == "pyramid":                                                                    
    baseLength = int(input("Please enter the base length: "))                                
    heightLength = int(input("Please enter the height: "))
    def main():                                                                             
        result2 = round((pyramidVolume(baseLength,heightLength)),2)
        print ("A pyramid with base {} and height {} has a volume {}".format(baseLength,heightLength,result2))
    def pyramidVolume(baseLength, heightLength):                                            
        volume = ((1/3)*(baseLength**2)*(heightLength))
        return volume
    main()                                                                                   
    continue                                                                                
elif shape == "ellipsoid":                                                                  
    r1 = int(input("Please enter the longest radius: "))
    r2 =  int(input("Please enter the smaller radius: "))
    r3 = int(input("Please enter the third radius: "))
    import math                                                                             
    def main():                                                                             
        result3 = round(ellipsoidVolume(r1,r2,r3),2)
        print ('An ellipsoid with a radius of {}, {}, and {} has a volume {}'.format(r1,r2,r3,result3))
    def ellipsoidVolume(r1,r2,r3):                                                          
        volume = ((4/3)*(math.pi))*r1*r2*r3
        return volume
    main()
    continue                                                                                
elif shape == "quit":                                                                        
    print ("You have come to the end of the session.")
    print ("The volumes calculated for each shape are shown below.")
    print ("Cube: ")    #what I need to find out
    print ("Pyramid: ")  #same as above
    print ("Ellipsoid: ") # again
else:                                                                                       
    print ("That is not a proper shape")
    continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with 3 lists. So before your `while(True)`-loop you define the lists:

```
cubeList = []
pyramidList = []
ellipsoidList = []
```

Then in the main-function of your 3 volumes you can add the result to the list. For example for the pyramid you would have the following main function:

```
def main():
    result2 = round((pyramidVolume(baseLength,heightLength)),2)
    pyramidList.append(result2)
    print ("A pyramid with base {} and height {} has a volume {}".format(baseLength,heightLength,result2))
```

Now, every time the user calculates a volume, it will be added to one of the 3 lists. As a last step you can just print the list while the user wants to quit:

```
print ("Cube: {}".format(cubeList))
print ("Pyramid: {}".format(pyramidList))
print ("Ellipsoid: {}".format(ellipsoidList))
```

If you want to have the list nicely formated, you can do something like this:

```
cs = ""
for ind,el in enumerate(cubeList):
    cs += "Shape {} has volume {}".format(ind,el)
print ("Cube: {}".format(cs))
```